# stream raspivid output with nodejs to a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I'm trying to stream the output of raspivid to a web application with nodejs. The problem is that the data that I'm streaming cannot be displayed. This is the code for the node server:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

const raspivid = spawn(
  'raspivid',
  ['-t', '0', '-w', '300', '-h', '300', '-hf', '-fps', '20', '-o', '-']);

raspivid.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  var base64Image = data.toString('base64');
  io.emit('videostream', base64Image);
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

For the web application I tried many things, I tried to display the stream in an image tag as well as in a video tag, so I use one of the following tags:

```
<video id="video" width="400" height="300"></video>
<img id="img" src="">
```

And I tried to display the stream trying the following things:

```
var socket = io(),
  video = document.getElementById('video'),
  img = document.getElementById('img'),
  vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

socket.on('videostream', function(stream) {
  var contentType = 'image/png';
  img.src = ' data:image/png;base64,' + stream;//op1 doesn't work
  var blob = b64toBlob(stream, contentType);
  img.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(blob);//op2 doesn't work
  video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(blob);//op3 doesn't work
  video.play();
});
```

Can someone tell me how can I display the stream in the browser or point me in the right direction? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was not able to find simple solution for this.
One way to overcome the problem is to use ffmpeg or MJPEG-streamer to stream the input from raspivid as a video stream that can be displayed in the browser, detailed information of how to do this can be found in the following posts:
  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/how-can-i-stream-h-264-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module-via-a-web-serve

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/stream-video-from-the-raspberry-pi-camera-to-web-browsers-even-on-ios-and-android

Alternatively you can take pictures between small periods of time and then send them in a stream like is better described here:
  http://thejackalofjavascript.com/rpi-live-streaming/

I hope one of the solutions mentioned above will be useful to someone else :)